# Using WebRTC to stream audio to java server

Tags: java, webrtc

I'm afraid the answer to my question is no, but I'm asking it anyway just in case.

**What I would like to do is stream audio from a chrome browser to a server written in Java via WebRTC. My understanding is that to accomplish this I need a Java implementation of peerconnection. All I've found so far is the libjingle Java API for android but that hasn't been particularly useful for integrating into my server app (I'd prefer an actual Java implementation, not just a C++ wrapper).**

If a library to do what I want really doesn't exist does anyone have any pointers for how I might approach actually implementing the WebRTC spec myself? When I look at such a large spec I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink). We (I helped develop it) wrote a Java implementation for it, as well as .NET and Objective C.

Comment: IceLink seems pretty good. It doesn't have many java examples, but since the API is fairly consistent I was able to get everything working based on the c++ examples. It's too bad that accepting a correct answer doesn't provide a +1.

Comment: is it for signaling or it can establish connection with js client and  handle srtp stream ?

Comment: We use WebSync for signalling, but you can use whatever you want, it's swappable.

Comment: Is it only signal server or is it complete web-rtc engine which can handle SRTP stream ?

Comment: The SRTP stream is not signalling; that's WebRTC, and is integrated into IceLink.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete Java WebRTC signal server written with Java i/o sockets. https://code.google.com/p/jfraggws/ Just make a project, include the .Java file and include rt.jar in the project. Next set the port on the Html 5 client and plug in your servers IP. You now have java webrtc.

Comment: Your library overrides several core java classes, which is pretty sketchy, and is severely lacking in documentation. The sample example that comes with your code is clearly using websockets (based on the code) but it's not clear if you are actually using a WebRTC peerconnection or not.